# Change tooltip format on C3.js Chart

Tags: jquery, c3.js

I have a chart like this on my page:

```
var chart = c3.generate({
data: {
    columns: [
        ['data1', 30000, 20000, 10000, 40000, 15000, 250000],
        ['data2', 100, 200, 100, 40, 150, 250]
    ],
    axes: {
        data2: 'y2'
    }
},
axis : {
    y : {
        tick: {
            format: d3.format("s")
        }
    },
    y2: {
        show: true,
        tick: {
            format: d3.format("$")
        }
    }
},
tooltip: {
    format: {
        title: function (d) { return 'Data ' + d; },
        value: function (value, ratio, id) {
            var format = id === 'data1' ? d3.format(',') : d3.format('$');
            return format(value);
        }
           //value: d3.format(',') // apply this format to both y and y2
    }
}
});
```

It works fine but I have a button that changes the data:

```
$('#filter').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    chart.load({
        unload: true,
        columns: [
            ['data1', 70, 100, 140, 80],
            ['data2', 30, 140, 40, 80]
        ]
    });
});
```

After the change I want to change the tooltip format but I can't find a method to change and update it. Is it possible to do it without recreating the chart everytime someone clicks the button?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The crucial thing to remember is that the title, format, etc are functions that are run each time the tool tip is displayed - so all one needs do is introduce logic into those functions that lets one toggle the desired format.

In your case perhaps you could just use a simple variable to represent the format as a number. e.g.

```
var format = 1;
```

Then set then conditions in your format functions...

```
tooltip: {
    format: {
        title: function (d) { 
            if(format === 1) return 'Data ' + d; 
            if(format === 2) return 'New Data ' + d; 
        },
        // etc ...
    }
}
```

Finally set the format you want when you click...

```
$('#filter').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    format = 2; // simple
    chart.load({
        unload: true,
        columns: [
            ['data1', 70, 100, 140, 80],
            ['data2', 30, 140, 40, 80]
        ]
    });
});
```

Obviously this is a really simple example, but the principal remains the same - put the logic to set the desired format in the run-time functions for displaying the tooltips - this way you can change how they are displayed without recreating the chart each time.

There is no reason at all you could not take the function approach level or two higher in the object hierarchy - for example at the format or tooltip level.

Whenever something expects an object or value - you can always use a function as long as it returns the type as required. e.g.

```
var formatx = { ... } 

tooltip: {
   format: function() {
      switch(format) {
         case 1: return { ... },
         case 2: return formatx,
         ...
      }
   }
}
```